# How to find $E[min(X_1,...,X_n)]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am given the following density function:

$f\left( x\right) =\begin{cases}1 (0 < x < 1)\\ 0 (otherwise)\end{cases}$

I am told to find the $E[Min(X_1,...,X_n)]$

This basically implies that I must find the cdf of $Min(X_1,...,X_n)$.
We will then do $E[X] = \int ^{\infty }_{0} [1-F_{X}\left( x\right)] dx $ to find $E[Min(X_1,...,X_n)]$.

Now I need to understand how to find the cdf itself. However I have no clue on how to proceed from there. So I look up the solution offered for this problem:

$$P[min(X,..,Xn) \leq x] =$$
$$1- P[min(X,..,Xn) > x] =$$
$$1- (P[X_1 > x] )^n =$$
$$1 - (1 - P[X_1 \leq x])^n =$$
$$1 - (1 - f_{x_{1}}(x))^n =$$
$$1 - (1 - x)^n$$

Can someone explain what's happening?

Comment: What step don’t you understand?

Comment: Mainly you just need to note that if the minimum of $n$ numbers is greater than $x$ then all of the $n$ numbers must be greater than $x$: $\{X>x\}=\cap_i \{X_i >x\}$ where $X=\min\{X_1, \dotsc, X_n\}$. Then take these events’ probabilities and use properties of IID.